# Represent a function as a difference of two convex function

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

I know that if $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is $C^2$ it can be rewrite as a difference of two convex function. I ask to you if there is someone who know if it's possible extend this property to the function which have $\mathbb{R}^n$ as domain.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A $C^2$-function as difference of two convex functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2693451/a-c2-function-as-difference-of-two-convex-functions)

Comment: There is an answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2693451/a-c2-function-as-difference-of-two-convex-functions

Comment: In the question of the links the function is a one variable function, I want to know if a multivariable function have the same proprietie. For me can be helpful either have some bibliographies reference. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, for example:

If $f \in C^2(D,\mathbb{R})$ and $D$ a non-empty, convex and compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $f$ is a dc-function, i.e. the difference of two convex functions.

The proof can't be done the same way as in $\mathbb{R}$. Note that in this statement you need a **compact** subset.

Here is a reference (Sanjo's answer): https://math.stackexchange.com/a/843020/797553

For a proof use $g(x)=f(x) + \rho/2 \cdot x^Tx$ and $h(x)=\rho/2 \cdot x^Tx$, where $\rho=\left| ~min ~\{\lambda_{min}(Hessf(x)): x\in D\} ~\right|$. Then $f=g-h$. Note that $\rho$ only exists as $D$ is compact.

EDIT: For $D=\mathbb{R}^n$ the statement is still true. (see [Konno H., Thach P.T., Tuy H. (1997) D.C. Functions and D.C. Sets. In: Optimization on Low Rank Nonconvex Structures. Nonconvex Optimization and Its Applications, vol 15. Springer, Boston, MA]). In this book you'll also find a proof for the statement above.

Comment: So if D isn't  compact the tesis is not true. Do you have an example of a function which is in $C^2(D,\mathbb{R})$ (with D non-compact set) but it isn't representable as a difference of two convex function?

Comment: I don't know if the satetment is false for $n \geq 2$ and $D$ non-compact. Only that we would need a different proof/approach. I guess it's false, but I'm not sure. A counterexample to find is really hard and I don't know any easy one.

Comment: Also for $D=\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f \in C^2$, the statement is true. See my edit.